# SQL Error #1064 while Create Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create an Trigger within my MySQL Database, but I always get the Error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`BEGIN DECLARE tmppl INT; SELECT MAX(PortListID) FROM pj_servers INTO t`' at line 2

This is the query.
I just can't find the error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER init_new_server AFTER INSERT ON pj_servers
BEGIN
    DECLARE tmppl INT;
    SELECT MAX(PortListID) FROM pj_servers INTO tmppl;

    INSERT INTO pj_servers (Registered, PortListID)
    VALUES (Current_Timestamp, (tmppl+1))
    WHERE pj_servers.ID = NEW.ID;

    INSERT INTO pj_serverports (PortList, Port, isOpen, Script)
    VALUES (tmppl+1, 80, TRUE, "say(\"Hallo\"");
END$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html):

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    TRIGGER trigger_name
    trigger_time trigger_event
    ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
    trigger_body

trigger_time: { BEFORE | AFTER }

trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }
```

so probably you're missing `FOR EACH ROW` in the first line

Answer (score 0):

OK found it, dnll was right with the `FOR EACH ROW` but also I tried to make the `Insert` with an `WHERE` statement, wich clearly couldn't work.

fixed code is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER init_new_server AFTER INSERT ON pj_servers
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN
DECLARE tmppl INT;

SELECT MAX( PortListID )
FROM pj_servers
INTO tmppl;

UPDATE pj_servers SET Registered = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
PortListID = tmppl +1 WHERE pj_servers.ID = NEW.ID;

INSERT INTO pj_serverports( PortList, Port, isOpen, Script )
VALUES (
tmppl +1, 80,
TRUE , "say(\"Hallo\")"
);

END
```